# Sphere inscribed in a cone

Tags: geometry, volume, spheres

If a cone of height h and radius r has a sphere inscribed in it such that it touches the base and the curved surface area, how can I find the radius of the sphere? (Is this in the level of a 9 grader?)

Comment: This isn't a homework

Comment: Can you made an image please?

Comment: Actually this considered the image to large, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the cone a right-circular cone? Consider the following cross-section picture.

[image]

There are two similar triangles in the picture: $\bigtriangleup ABD$ and $\bigtriangleup COD$.

Use the property of similar triangles and form the following:
$$\frac{BD}{BA}=\frac{OD}{OC}$$

Note that $AB$ is the radius of the cone. $OD$ is equal to the height of the cone minus the radius of the sphere.$OC$ is the radius of the sphere.

Question for you: can you write $\frac{BD}{BA}=\frac{OD}{OC}$ in terms of $h$ and $r$ and solve for $OC$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the cross-sectional diagram (i.e. What does the object look like if I slice it down the middle?)

You should end up with an isosceles triangle with a circle inscribed.

Comment: Sorry to be so late, I appreciate your answer.